# Azure Logic App : how to trigger logic app workflow 2000+ times?

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-logic-apps

```
"triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "concurrency": {
                        "maximumWaitingRuns": 99,
                        "runs": 1
                    }
                },
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
```

From the above code can I **increase** the trigger amount from **"maximumWaitingRuns": 99** to **2000+**?
If yes then how?
I also want to trigger it 2000+ times using **single click.**

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround to make the workflow run multiple times is to use a recurrence trigger instead of an HTTP trigger.

[image]

Another workaround would be mentioning the iterations and run the workflow through Postman. After saving your request to one of your collections, navigate to your **collection >> Run >> Mention the number of iterations >> Run Sample**.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok but my requirement is that, Can we increase the "runs:1" to "runs:2000" limit in "runtimeConfiguration: concurrency" ??

Comment: @UjjvalDarji, No you cant the maximum runs can be of only 100